# Reference Request: Replacement for Anderson and Fuller

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules

I'm working through *Rings and Categories of Modules* by Anderson and Fuller. It's a great text, but I would like a more modern replacement. The text focuses too much on the language of generation and cogeneration, which is less popular nowadays. It also references itself a little too much for my taste; I would prefer a text that repeats itself in proofs to emphasize techniques over a text that takes a minimal path to build up to results.

I'd like to hear suggestions for a modern introductory text on rings and modules that could serve as a partial replacement for Anderson and Fuller. Thanks!

Comment: Very strange! What do you believe is a more "modern" approach that is more popular?

Comment: I don't know honestly. This is why I'm asking. If I find something on my own then I'll come back and post it here.

Comment: ah, so you don't even really have anything to back up your statements. I was wondering because it is a perfectly good text, pretty much devoid of all the problems you describe, and it is amplified by even more recent texts.

Comment: Which statement concerns you? I will back it up for you if that would help you direct me to a suitable text. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're trying to say. There's no need to defend this text against me; I said that I like it. I'm just looking for alternatives to go with it.

Comment: Dear @ebrahim : You said (in almost as many words) that A&F's approach is outmoded, and my question is again (if you have an answer now) "what do you believe is more modern and popular that makes you say this?"

Comment: I already explained this. The language of generation and cogeneration is not that popular, so I'd rather avoid it. I certainly didn't say that AF is outmoded. I just want something to replace it which is at least as modern; more modern would be good if there is such a thing.

Comment: If you think it's unpopular, you must be comparing it to another approach. But when I ask you what the approach is, you say you don't know. I don't think you are supporting your claim about it being unpopular at all. So far you've just said it is unpopular and outmoded by your fiat.

Comment: I never said that the text was unpopular. I don't know what you're talking about, and I'm not interested in bickering over it. I did end up finding a good supplement to Anderson and Fuller, which I'm posting as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I just understood what you meant. Okay maybe the gen/cogen language is still popular, I don't know. But I don't care to argue; I just wanted a good text with readable and memorable proofs, and you've been no help at all. I did end up finding a good supplement to Anderson and Fuller, which I'm posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding that T.Y. Lam's *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings* worked as an excellent supplement to A&F.

Comment: Both A&F, this book you mention, and Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings* are core ring/module theory books in my library. Another good and massive book is Wisbauer's *Foundations of ring and module theory*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the massive book too!